# What is a different between different kind of pushup workout?

Tags: exercise, body-fat, push-ups

I want to know there is number of variety pushup styles.

1. Traditional pushup
2. Wide-grip pushup
3. Close-grip pushup
4. Clap pushup
5. One-leg pushup
6. Dead-stop pushup
7. Eccentric pushup
8. Spider-Man pushup
9. One-armed incline pushup
10. Decline pushup
11. Incline pushup

Please explain what is different between each pushups and how it is effect for body?

Comment: Please do your own research, there are plenty of resources which excercise target which muscle. Then come back and ask specific questions. Flagged as too broad.

Comment: @Christian - I don't think this is too broad, as there are a grand total of 11 exercises. Yes, it does show a lack of prior research, but we shouldn't castigate newer users over that. I would agree if the question was stated "I see a lot of different pushup exercises, what are the differences in all of them?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Traditional pushup**

I think you mean a push up with elbows sliding down and up your torso, this one uses the most muscles in your body. If you do this exercise weighted either with a [dipping belt/rope](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ybv6dMzokgs), with bands or with plates on your back you can also get a good Gluteus and calf exercise out of it.

**Wide grip pushups**

Pushing with your elbows parallel to your feet in order to make a **T** is probably going to seriously damage your shoulder.

Try raising your arms in a **T** position while standing, then push forward while bending your elbows, you will notice your shoulders being rotated and rounded forward and downward. This is one of the weakest position for your ligaments and tendons on the shoulder, avoid it to avoid injuries.

**Close grip pushups**

This one puts the Pectoralis major in a  really disadvantageous position letting all the work to the Pectoralis minor,Trapizius,Serratus anterior,Rhomboid,Deltoid and Tricep.

This one is quite good if you want to overload those muscles while sacrificing a bit of chest size.

**Clapping pushup**

Good exercise for cardio and explosiveness. One of the most functional exercise that carry over to sports and martial arts.

Mix it with some clapping inverted rows, and jumping air squats to get one of the most effective cardio workout.

You can also do it each morning as daily conditioning to start your day. It might also save your heart over the long run.

**One legged pushup**

This is pretty much just a normal push up that requires a little bit more stabilization and is kind of ''heavier'' while building some endurance in the Gluteus.

**Deadstop pushup**

This eliminates elasticity and forces the body to become stronger in it's weakest positions. It's one of these exercises where you will get stronger faster than you build muscle, like the deadlift for example.

**Eccentric pushup**

This is bodybuilding move, quite the opposite of deadstop.
Muscles are like bands, they are going to be damaged during the stretched position not the contracted one or at least not as much.

Eccentric exercises are overall good to build muscle and endurance when you don't really care that much about strength.

**Spiderman pushup**

This is a better version of the one legged push up as it puts even more weight on your upper body and uses some lower oblique.

I actually did built my Adonis Belt by doing spiderman push ups with resistance bands on my legs, when I pull the leg up to my chest or out to my elbow I also pull the band and get some resistance. In theory this exercise has infinite loading potential because you can use as many bands as you can afford.

**One arm pushup and inclined pushup**

Like any unilateral exercise it's good to fix imbalances  while also giving some passive work to the muscles on the sides of your core like the Quadratus Lumborum and the Oblique muscles.

Also, progressive angulation is a good way to get stronger. 
Starting from an high incline you can increase the angle more and more until you are able to do it 180° on the ground.

**Decline pushup**

This might or might not carry over to the overhead press or the handstand push up depending and the width of your torso and the length of your arms because strength is joint to angle specific.

And also eliminates some work from the chest and overloads the Trapezius muscles and the long head of the Tricep while also putting some more emphasis on the frontal Deltoid, even more than the close grip pushup.